# Graph records in "open" status per day in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have records that have a "start" and "end" date. Records that are still "open" are lacking an end date. I want to create a graph that shows how many records were "open" for each day.

I began by setting a start date and end date parameter for the x-axis and setting the interval to one. So for example, I set the parameter to 3/27 through 3/30. The graph x-axis shows 3/27, 3/28, 3/29. I think I probably have to do something like, count the number of true statements per x-axis value that meet the following: "open date" >= x-axis value and "close date" <= x-axis value (meaning the record was "open" for that x-axis value).

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any native way to use the labels generated in a chart in further calculations that generate the chart data.

Assuming your **Data Source** is a database, I think your best option would be to use a stored procedure that generates a list of dates internally based on your `start` and `end` parameters, then uses this list of dates to create your desired dataset, i.e. one row per date with an open records value. Then the dataset matches your chart requirements exactly.

If you're using the data elsewhere in the report it may mean multiple datasets, but in terms of complexity and actually getting your desired result it seems like the simplest and quickest option.

Comment: I ended up doing this while implementing the same logic I suggested in my original post. Works great!